# LineHeight not set in Report Builder

Tags: sql-server, reportbuilder3.0, reportbuilder

I have an adress in a textbox in my report. This is always more than one line. But it looks not as I want, because I cannot set the LineHeight. I tried following:

- Set the LineHeight on Textbox with the LineHeight Property
- Use HTML and CSS: I used p, div and span Tag with style:'line-height:1.5;'
- Set the LineSpacing to Custom and set it to 15pt.

But it always looks not like I want. It looks like this:

[image]

The line spacing should be bigger. Anyone know a way to create line spaceing bigger?

Comment: You could try an expression (i.e; =IIF(IncreaseHeight, "20pt", "2pt"))

Comment: @jw11432 This also not work. I don't know what the problem is.